# AJAX php gallery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, gallery

I have a gallery on my site that needs to change when a user selects an option from the dropdown menu (the options represent locations).

At present I have the following two options:

```
<select class="form-control" id="photomenu">
    <option value="Beckmouth Area">Beckmouth Area</option>
    <option value="Barras Square area">Barras Square area</option>
</select>
```

My Jquery selects the chosen value and sends it to my AJAX request like so:

```
<script>
                 $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#photomenu").change(function(){


                        var option = $("#photomenu option:selected").val();


                        var url = "access_database.php";

                        $.post(url, option, function(data)

                            {
                                $("#staithes_gallery").html(data)

                            });


                    }); 
                     });
                    </script>
```

My `access_database.php` looks like:

```
<?php 

$folder_location = $_GET["option"];

$path = "photos_staithes/Thumbnails/";

 //connect to staithesbooks table
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "***********";
 $password = "***********";
 $dbname = "*********";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql_select_photo = "SELECT * FROM `staithesphotos` WHERE `folder` = '$folder_location'";

$results = $conn->query($sql_select_photo);

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

        //create a list of all names and folder locations
        $name[] = $row["name"];

    }

        //create the photo gallery
        for ($x=0; $x<count($name); $x++)
        {
            $photo_gallery .= "<div class='col-md-4 work-grid animated wow slideInLeft'>
                                <a href='$path$folder_lcation$name[$x]' data-lightbox='featured' data-title='' style='cursor:pointer'><div class='item'>
                                    <img src='$path$folder_location/$name[$x]' height='431' width='594' title='name' />
                                    <div class='caption' style='display: none;'>
                                        <h2>Some Title</h2>
                                        <p>This is a caption to end all captions</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </a></div>";    
        }

};


echo $photo_gallery;
```

?>

I have tested that the `PHP` works by providing a static file location for `$folder_location`.

Upon execution of the `AJAX call` I wish to update the html within `#staithes_gallery` with the new gallery.

Through testing and outputting the result to an alert box I simply receive object Object. I'm unsure what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wait, what is your real problem here? You having trouble to get what PHP returns back from the request or any problem with `$folder_location` value or query ?

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem lies. The jquery just returns object Object instead of the new html text. Each component I have tested separately and seems to work. I'm not sure if the value isn't correctly to the php or whether the data returned from the php is erroneous

Comment: After set `$sql_select_photo` put `echo $sql_select_photo; exit;` and call the url directly in your browser. Then check your query in your db.

Comment: The query is fine and works. Running the script will produce the gallery. It simply doesn't work with the jquery. Either the value of the option isn't being sent, or the echo at the bottom of the php isn't being read correctly.

Comment: Try this: `$.post(url, { option: option }, function(data) `

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have it working.

I had to use .html() and not .val()

Thanks!